# How to establish communication between Java and PHP?

Tags: java, php, multithreading, sockets, wamp

I am using WAMP and I have a module which supports WebSockets. I intend to implement a standalone Java project which will start WAMP in a new `Thread`, initializes a Java `ServerSocket` at a given `port` and at localhost as address and to listen to connections on that `port`. So far I am able to start WAMP, but I have a problem with initializing the `ServerSocket` and receiving actual messages. These are my Java classes:

**WebSocket.java**

```
package websocket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WebSocket {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String command = "";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            String[] commandArray = command.split(" ");
            Command.executeCommand(commandArray);
            command = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Command: " + command);
        } while (!command.equals("exit"));
        Command.exit();
        System.out.println("Finished");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

**Command.java**

```
package websocket;

public class Command {
    private static WAMP wamp;
    private static WS ws;

    public static void WAMPMethod(String[] commandArray) {
        if (wamp == null) {
            wamp = WAMP.create(commandArray);
        }
    }

    public static void WSMethod(String[] commandArray) {
        if (ws == null) {
            ws = WS.create();
        }
    }

    private static void stopThread(Thread t) {
        if (t != null) {
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void exit() {
        stopThread(wamp);
        stopThread(ws);
    }

    public static void executeCommand(String[] commandArray) {
        if (commandArray[0].equals("WAMP")) {
            WAMPMethod(commandArray);
        } else if (commandArray[0].equals("WS")) {
            WSMethod(commandArray);
        }
    }
}
```

**WAMP.java**

```
package websocket;

public class WAMP extends Thread {

    public String[] command;

    public WAMP(String[] command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public static WAMP create(String[] command) {
        WAMP wamp = new WAMP(command);
        wamp.start();
        return wamp;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (command[1].equals("Start")) {
            StartWAMP();
        }
    }

    private void StartWAMP() {
        try {
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            runTime.exec("C:\\wamp\\wampmanager.exe");
            System.out.println("WAMP is started");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }        
    }

}
```

**WS.java**

```
package websocket;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class WS extends Thread {

    public static int port = 4444;

    public static WS create() {
        WS ws = new WS();
        ws.start();
        return ws;
    }

    public WS() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, 50, addr);
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String command = "";
            System.out.println("WS Started");
            while (!command.equals("exit")) {
                command = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(command);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

When I start the Java project, I issue `WAMP Start` and `WS` commands and my output is:

> WAMP Start
>
> Command: WAMP Start
>
> WAMP is started
>
> WS
>
> Command: WS

The WS Thread enters a waiting state at the line of

```
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

After WAMP is started, I execute the following PHP script:

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
$mess = "This is a message";
socket_sendto($sock, $mess, strlen($mess), 0, '127.0.0.1', 4444);
socket_close($sock);
```

however, my Java program does not continue its process, which means that it still did not establish a socket connection. How could I fix this, what am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the WS is blocking in "new ServerSocket(port, 50, addr);"? Usually it is blocking in the accept() method.

Comment: Using the localhost binding is the default. It is therefore enough to just create the server with the port: "new ServerSocket(port);"

Comment: @Heri, nice catch, it is blocking at the accept() indeed, I mistakenly copied and pasted the wrong line and did not observe it. However, I am not sure your second comment is accurate, as while debugging this yesterday I have seen that the address used was 0.0.0.0

Comment: Yes, the accept method blocks until a client connects. Usually one passes the received socket to an own thread to serve this client. The main thread immediatly goes back to accept for waiting for the next client.

Comment: Can you open the socket localhost:4444 by another tool? e.g. telnet or socktest.exe?

Comment: @Heri, I have chosen a different approach since then and am close to success, but will put back the old code (which I still have for the case that I receive an answer or suggestion), but it will be done later today, as this is a hobby project and I have to work on my main project for many hours today. Please, bear with me.

Comment: @Heri, running the command of telnet 127.0.0.1 4444 successfully establishes the connection and then the data is successfully sent.

Comment: So your problem must be on the PHP client side. Here I cannot give you good advise because I am not a PHP expert.